# how can i retrieve an url from firebase and show it as clickable link in react native?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, hyperlink

`<Text> {website link}</Text>`
it appeared as a text and now I want it to be a clickable link, so how can use the OpenURL and send a firestore field in its parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
import { Linking } from 'react-native';

// define websiteLink variable somewhere 

....

<Text 
      onPress={() => Linking.openURL(websiteLink)}>
  {websiteLink}
</Text>
```